# How to show map on another page and view fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, google-maps-api-3

I use map on my project MVC. when click button 'filter' show some point on map and show to same page.Also i want use another button (Showbutton) to show map on another page without layout. it means that map view in full screen. Event of this click button :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Showbutton").click(function () {
        var Desert = $("#DesertID").val();
        var Type = $("#meter_TypeMeterID_FK").val();
        var Usemeter = $("#meter_UseMeterID_FK").val();
        var Affair = $("#meter_AffairID_FK").val();
        var GroupMeter = $("#meter_GroupMeterID_FK").val();
        var Status = $("#modem_StatusID_FK").val();
        var StatusMeter = $("#meter_StatusID_FK").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("ShowMapOnOtherPage", "Map")'
            dataType: "JSon",
            data: { "Affair": Affair, "Type": Type, "Desert": Desert, "Usemeter": Usemeter, "GroupMeter": GroupMeter, "Status": Status, "StatusMeter": StatusMeter },
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });
    });
```

when Showbutton clicked, run method "ShowMapOnOtherPage" :

```
 public ActionResult ShowMapOnOtherPage(string desertName, string Type, string Usemeter, string Affair, string GroupMeter, string Status, string StatusMeter)
    {
       //Do something
        return View("~/Views/Map/ShowMapOnOtherPage.cshtml");
    }
```

but do not show view 'ShowMapOnOtherPage.cshtml'. why?!

Comment: hi your ajax result how can i handle it?

Comment: your ajax result send to specific div to append so you can view result

Comment: @BhadreshShiroya hi, my result ajax did not send to my view. I want to show in another view. this view is Index and when clicked button and run method 'ShowMapOnOtherPage' result send to 'ShowMapOnOtherPage.cshtml'.

Comment: yes but your ajax call can not be transfer result to another page you can submit form so handle it

Comment: See demo click map button http://prod.agilityintegrations.com/PregraCalendar/Schedule.action

Comment: @BhadreshShiroya oh thanks. how can i submit form?

Comment: @BhadreshShiroya Thanks in advance, when i clicked Showbutton did not use ajax So how call my method of controller ? , please guide me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106316/discussion-between-bhadresh-shiroya-and-mahdis-dezfouli).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Create Form

```
<form action="@Url.Action("ShowMapOnOtherPage", "Map")" method="post" name="mapform" id="mapform">
    <input type="hidden" name="desertName" value="" id="mapdesertName"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Type" value="" id="mapType"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Usemeter" value="" id="mapUsemeter"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Affair" value="" id="mapAffair"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="GroupMeter" value="" id="mapGroupMeter"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Status" value="" id="mapStatus"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="StatusMeter" value="" id="mapStatusMeter"/>
</form> 


<script type="text/javascript">
$("#Showbutton").click(function () {
    var Desert = $("#DesertID").val();
    var Type = $("#meter_TypeMeterID_FK").val();
    var Usemeter = $("#meter_UseMeterID_FK").val();
    var Affair = $("#meter_AffairID_FK").val();
    var GroupMeter = $("#meter_GroupMeterID_FK").val();
    var Status = $("#modem_StatusID_FK").val();
    var StatusMeter = $("#meter_StatusID_FK").val();

    $("#mapdesertName").val(Desert);
    $("#mapType").val(Type);
    $("#mapUsemeter").val(Usemeter);
    $("#mapAffair").val(Affair)   ;
    $("#mapGroupMeter").val(GroupMeter);
    $("#mapStatus").val(Status);
    $("#mapStatusMeter").val(StatusMeter);
    document.mapform.submit();
});
</script>
```